# Allocating memory to a different struct changes pointer members of a completely different struct

Tags: c, struct

Allocating memory to `matrix` struct with some values of `[row, column]` pair for `create_matrix` function changes values of  `layer->values` pointer which has no relation with `matrix` struct being allocated.

Some tested `[row, column]` values are:

```
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
```

gdb output for [2,2] i.e `create_matrix(2, 2)`:

```
(gdb) print *prev_layer
$1 = {
  nodes = 2,
  weights = 0xb6438030,
  biases = 0xb6438060,
  values = 0xb6438080
}
(gdb) n
(before allocation): 0xb6438080
50          weights = create_matrix(2, 2);
(gdb) n
51          if (!weights)
(gdb) print *prev_layer
$2 = {
  nodes = 2,
  weights = 0xb6438030,
  biases = 0xb64380b0, <- this changes
  values = 0xb64380c0 <- this changes
}
(gdb)
```

From above it seems that it assigns last two pointer associated with memory allocation to last two members of the struct. *Sometimes even `NULL` pointer*

Program output for `[2,2]`:

```
Values of prev_layer->values
(before allocation): 0xb6438080
(after allocation): 0xb64380c0
```

Code used:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double **m;
} matrix;

typedef struct layer {
    int nodes;
    matrix *weights;
    matrix *biases;
    matrix *values;
} layer;

matrix *create_matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    matrix *ret = malloc(sizeof(matrix));
    if (!ret)
        return NULL;
    double **m = malloc(rows * sizeof(double *));
    if (!m)
        return NULL;

    for (int c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
        m[c] = calloc(cols, sizeof(double));
        if (!m[c]) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    ret->rows = rows;
    ret->cols = cols;
    ret->m = m;

    return ret;
}

layer *create_layer(int nodes, const layer *prev_layer) {

    matrix *weights, *biases;
    /* Just after allocation it changes pointer of
     * prev_layer->bias and prev_layer->values
     * to last to matrix row allocations
     * bug works with values in ordered pair [row, col] => [1,2], [2,2],
     * doesn't with when used values like [5,3]
     * */
    if (prev_layer)
        printf("(before allocation): %p\n", prev_layer->values);

    weights = create_matrix(1,2);
    if (!weights)
        return NULL;

    if (prev_layer)
        printf("(after allocation): %p\n", prev_layer->values);

    biases = create_matrix(1, nodes);
    if (!biases)
        return NULL;

    matrix *values = create_matrix(1, nodes);
    if (!values)
        return NULL;

    layer *ret = malloc(sizeof(layer *));
    if (!ret)
        return NULL;

    ret->nodes = nodes;
    ret->weights = weights;
    ret->biases = biases;
    ret->values = values;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int nodes[] = {2, 2};
    layer *p1 = create_layer(2, NULL);
    layer *p2 = create_layer(2, p1);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler: clang 9.0.0

Comment: `for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)` That looks wrong. Need to iterate over the rows not the columns. So the result is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `layer *ret = malloc(sizeof(layer *));` is one major problem. I suggest you use the pattern `layer *ret = malloc(sizeof *ret);` instead.

Comment: @kaylum I have edited and tested it but doesn't fix the problem used with `[2,2]`

Comment: He has a keen eye... You were short on allocation by at minimum `sizeof (2_pointers+1_int)` -- not including padding.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah `sizeof(layer *)` is only size of one pointer `8` and `4` on 32-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type used to compute the allocation size is incorrect in:

```
layer *ret = malloc(sizeof(layer *));  // should be sizeof(layer)
```

You allocate the size of a pointer instead of the size of a structure.

To avoid such silly mistakes, you can use the destination pointer type directly:

```
layer *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
```

Alternately, you could use allocation wrapper macros and rely on the compiler to detect mismatched types:

```
#define ALLOC(t)           ((t *)calloc(1, sizeof(t)))
#define ALLOC_ARRAY(t, n)  ((t *)calloc(n, sizeof(t)))

layer *ret = ALLOC(layer);
```

Answer (score 1):

The line with `ret`'s `malloc` needs to make enough space for a whole `layer`, however you have asked for enough space for a `layer*`.

So

```cpp
layer *ret = malloc(sizeof(layer *));
```

should be

```cpp
layer *ret = malloc(sizeof(layer));
```